# Memory Utilization inceased on Routing Engine in Juniper MX

Tags: juniper-junos, juniper-mx

[image: Memory Utilization Graph]

We recently faced high memory utilization on primary RE of Juniper MX. I have attached graph of Memory Utilization . It was as a result for copying some files from Backup RE to Primary RE (This is which I am just guessing). Now when we were done with file copying , the memory that jumped from 30 to 52 is still staying at 52 .

So my question is that will RE0 memory stay there for long time ? (chances are it may increase from 52 to 100 due to some routing changes or something else) Or it can revert to previous value of 30?

If we wan to bring back Memory to its original value of 30 can we do this?

Further can we check from logs / commands what caused the memory to go high.

Thanks !!!!!!

[RE Memory Utilization Updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzf2W.png)

Comment: Can you provide the SNMP OID that you're polling for Memory Utilisation?  It may be that your graph is mislabelled, and you're actually looking at the output of the filesystem

Comment: @BenjaminDale. Nope Sir. While writng this query , I verified from CLI that RE memory utilization has indeed went high and this is what cacti reflected. Furthermore , the more interesting thing is that RE memory utilization has fallen back to original value. I have attached the new updated graph. Does this means that Memory went high as a result of copying files?

Comment: @BenjaminDale. For SNMP OID of RE memory Utilization , we are using this value [.1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.13.1.11.9.1.0.0].

Comment: @BenjaminDale. The above value is for RE0. For RE1 the value will be [.1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.13.1.11.9.2.0.0] .

Comment: @NABEELNASIR What version of Junos are you running?  There can be differences in the calculation of "actual" memory utilization in the newer kernel.

Comment: @JordanHead. The JUNOS version is 15.1R5-S3.4.